# "Nós ossos que aqui estamos pelos vossos esperamos" - não deveria ter uma vírgula?

Tags: gramática, ortografia, português-europeu

Na entrada da [Capela dos Ossos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capela_dos_Ossos), em Portugal, há a seguinte frase:

> Nos ossos qve aqvi estamos pelos vossos esperamos

[image: Entrada da capela com a frase citada acima]

Para dar mais contexto à mensagem, aqui está uma breve explicação encontrada na Wikipédia:

> Foi construída no século XVII por iniciativa de três monges franciscanos que, dentro do espírito da altura (contra-reforma religiosa, de acordo com as normativas do Concílio de Trento), pretendeu transmitir a mensagem da transitoriedade da vida, tal como se depreende do célebre aviso à entrada: "Nós ossos que aqui estamos pelos vossos esperamos".

Ler essa frase me parece estranho, sinto a falta de uma vírgula (ou duas). O português mudou bastante do século XVII para cá, e por isso estou em dúvida se isso é apenas uma variação da língua ao longo do tempo. Imagino que a frase pudesse ser escrita das seguintes maneiras:

1. Nós ossos que aqui estamos**,** pelos vossos esperamos.
2. Nós**,** ossos que aqui estamos**,** pelos vossos esperamos.

Realmente faltam vírgulas na frase original? Se sim, ambas opções acima seriam corretas? E, como bônus, essa necessidade da vírgula é realmente recente ou não se encontra na entrada por outros motivos?

Comment: Rafael, as regras de pontuação realmente eram diferentes. Porém, um uso interessante da vírgula é para dar a pausas no texto, a mudar, por exemplo, o ritmo. Então, talvez, a falta de vírgulas seja simplesmente para indicar que se deve ler sem pausas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Realmente faltam vírgulas na frase original? Se sim, ambas opções acima seriam corretas?

Se considerarmos

- "ossos que aqui estamos" como um aposto explicativo, [deve estar separado por pontuação do restante da frase](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint22.php), portanto opção 2 é a correta.
- "nós ossos" como o sujeito e "que aqui estamos" como uma oração subordinada adjetiva explicativa, [deve estar separada por vírgulas do restante da frase](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint36.php), portanto a opção 2 é a correta.
- "nós ossos" como o sujeito e "que aqui estamos" como uma oração subordinada adjetiva restritiva, [não pode ser separada por vírgulas do restante da frase](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint36.php), portanto está correta a frase original.

As três interpretações são aceitáveis a meu ver, então concluo que, haja vista a última interpretação, não deveria ter uma vírgula obrigatòriamente, embora a opção 2 também seja aceitável.

Comment: @LoremIpsum o segundo bullet não era sobre a opção 1? Acho que esse você trocou por engano hehe

Comment: @RafaelTavares Na verdade não, a opção 1 não é adequada em nenhum caso.